# Animating text to follow a path

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas about whether or not it was possible to have a canvas element on a page with a path along it and making some text travel along it and rotating as the path bends.

My current thought is to write a formula that determines the increment X step (so if its moving vertically, not to increase it by one to avoid sudden jumps), using that to get a Y value, and then a formula to work out the current gradient of the part of the line its on and use that to apply a rotation.

Any thoughts on this?

I want to use it as a funky way of showing a twitter feed on a website, already written a library that scrolls it along, but this is a bit boring.

Comment: also, any ideas on the formula to determine how much to increase the x by would be great :D

Comment: This could also be helpful in relation to `canvas`: http://simon.html5.org/dump/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be possible because of the sheer amount of things that you can do with `canvas` especially after seeing what has already been done. I'd suggest taking a look at [this](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#divingin) and [this](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/). I think the hardest part would be making sure that the text actually follows the path because both paths and transformations are easy.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a div which animates and rotates.

Try looking into [this](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [this](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html)

Comment: OR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438830/move-a-div-in-a-curved-path-like-tweening-in-flash-old-days