# Move a div in a curved path (like tweening in Flash old days)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'd like to build a function like

```
fromHeretoThere(x1,y1,x2,y2){
  //....
}
```

So that I can move a `<div>` or an image from one point on the HTML page to another point in a curve.

Is this doable only using Canvas? HTML5? any plugin/scripts yo suggest?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240052/how-would-you-animate-something-so-that-it-follows-a-curve

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit**: Here's a work in progress that packages up the second concept described below as a re-usable JS object. You can edit the code or visually drag the curve to see the resulting code:

http://phrogz.net/SVG/animation_on_a_curve.html

---

I'd personally use SVG, which makes this sort of thing (animating along an arbitrary Bézier curve) trivial using the [`<animateMotion>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateMotionElement) element. As a bonus, you can even cause it to calculate the rotation for you. Some examples:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/animate/animMotion01.svg
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/animateMotion
- http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/76/SolarSystem.svg

Note that you don't even have to actually use SVG to display the result; you could simply create an off-screen SVG with this animation and sample the transform of the animated element to get your desired point/rotation.

Alternatively (if you don't want the rotation, or want to calculate it yourself while controlling the rate of traversal) you can create an SVG path and just use [`getPointAtLength()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength)/[`getTotalLength()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getTotalLength) to find where you should be along the path at a given percentage of the total traversal distance. With this you don't even need an SVG document:

```
// Moving along an S curve from 0,0 to 250,450
var p = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','path');
p.setAttribute('d','M0,0 C350,20 -200,400 250,450');
var len = p.getTotalLength();
for (var i=0;i<=100;i+=10){
  var pct = i/100;
  var pt = p.getPointAtLength(pct*len);
  console.log( i, pt.x, pt.y );
}

// 0 0 0
// 10 65.54324340820312 10.656576156616211
// 20 117.17988586425781 49.639259338378906
// 30 120.2674789428711 114.92564392089844
// 40 100.49604034423828 178.4400177001953
// 50 78.06965637207031 241.1177520751953
// 60 63.526206970214844 305.9412841796875
// 70 74.59959411621094 370.6294860839844
// 80 122.1227798461914 415.8912658691406
// 90 184.41302490234375 438.8457336425781
// 100 250 450
```

Now all you have to do is set the `.style.top` and `.style.left` of your `<div>` or `<img>` appropriately. The only 'hard' part is deciding what you want to the curve to look like and defining [where to put the handles](http://phrogz.net/SVG/draggable-bezier.xhtml).

Comment: so how do I use this code? please who ever made this, put it in github with explanations..it looks awesome, but I only need the ability to set a curve to an animated element, I don't need all this dragging about of the SVG..

Comment: @vsync Look in the large "CODE" box on that page for JavaScript code you can copy/paste.

Comment: hmm but this is REALLY primitive..it doesn't let you set a path with more than 2 points....

Comment: @vsync That's true. So you turn to programming, and realize that you can use any SVG path with arbitrary shape. You just have to sample it as shown at the end of the above answer.

Comment: alright it's working nice :)
I think there should be an option in `CurveAnimator.prototype.animate` to animate the path in reverse as well. that would truly make this code great.

Comment: and what is `setStartDirection` for and how to use it?

Comment: I've modified your code to be lighter (also fixed some JS mistakes) and added support for reverse mode - http://codepen.io/yairEO/pen/cbkAF

Comment: This answer isn't up to date, since Chrome decided to make the SMIL animations deprecated. Their arguement was that there is a polyfill for SMIL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use at least:

- JavaScript (http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
- CSS3 Transitions (http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/)
- Canvas (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images)

CSS3 is probably the easiest, but JavaScript would be the most browser compatible.

You may also want to look at something like this:

- http://jsanim.com/
- http://processingjs.org/

What is it that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

sometimes googling is easier:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/anim/curve.html

Comment: The YUI library is no longer actively maintained

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery animate's step function you can animate in any curve you'd like.

For some things using a canvas is better, but for most small and simple animations just changing css values with jQuery (this is what animate does) is faster and simpler.

Here's a quick demonstration I made, built on top of the jQuery.path plugin : http://jsfiddle.net/zVddG/