# SVG trigger animation with event

Tags: javascript, events, animation, svg

how do I trigger an svg animate element to begin animating via javascript with an arbitrary event ? I'm imagining something like `begin="mySpecialEvent"`, then later I can send `mySpecialEvent` and the animation will start (or start again if it has already played).

Comment: +1 for a great question; I had been wondering the same thing for [a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438830/move-a-div-in-a-curved-path-like-tweening-in-flash-old-days/8439107#8439107). Now that I know how to kick off SVG animation on demand I can improve that answer. :)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Here's an article that covers what you need:
<strike>http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/advanced-svg-animation-techniques/</strike>

**Edit:** link is removed. Archived copies:

- https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera-static-backup/blob/master/http/dev.opera.com/articles/view/advanced-svg-animation-techniques/index.html
- http://web.archive.org/web/20140228202850/http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/advanced-svg-animation-techniques

In short:

1. Create the `<animation>` with `begin="indefinite"` so that it won't treat the animation as starting on document load. You can do this either via JavaScript or raw SVG source.
2. Call [`beginElement()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#__smil__ElementTimeControl__beginElement) on the `SVGAnimationElement` instance (the `<animate>` element) when you're ready for the animation to start. For your use case, use a standard `addEventListener()` callback to invoke this method when you're ready, e.g.

   ```
   myAnimationElement.addEventListener('mySpecialEvent',function(){
     myAnimationElement.beginElement();
   },false);
   ```

Comment: Great. In fact, simply calling `beginElement()` also made the job.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work on IE: "Object doesn't support property or method 'beginElement'"

Comment: @Starwave Very little works in IE. This is an unfortunate fact of web development.

Comment: @Phrogz the first link in answer is dead. Maybe it can be replaced by this one http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#SVGEvents ?

Comment: What are we going to use now that SVG animations are not longer supported?

Comment: @Persijn You can use **CSS animations** to achieve just about everything you can with SMIL.

Comment: SVG animations (aka SMIL animations) are no longer depreciated:
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM%5B126-150%5D

Comment: This has one drawback. You can no longer reference this animation to start others.

For example this is not working

```
  <animateMotion #flyUpText id="moveAnimation" dur="1s" begin="indefinite" path="M 0 0 25 -50" />
  <set attributeName="display" to="block" begin="moveAnimation.begin" />
  <set attributeName="display" to="none" begin="moveAnimation.end" />
```

Or am I doing someting wrong? When setting `begin` of `#flyUpText` to "0s" it's working as expected. Besides it's triggered right away.

Comment: [lol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455773/svg-trigger-animation-with-event#comment47001640_8458825), *`Very little works in IE`*

Answer (score 17):

Start an SVG animation:

Without javascript, using the "event-value" type of the begin attribute="id.event" (without an "on" prefix) on an animation element; or

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600px" height="400px">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100">
    <animate attributeName="x" begin="go.click" dur="2s" from="10" to="300" fill="freeze" />
  </rect>
</svg>

<button id="go">Go</button>
```

*(W3C 2018, "SVG Animations Level 2, Editor’s Draft", https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/), " Attributes to control the timing of the animation", "begin" attribute, "event-value" value type, https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#TimingAttributes*

From javascript, by setting an animation element's begin attribute to "indefinite"; and calling beginElement() from script;

```
function go () {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("animate");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].beginElement();
  }
}

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600px" height="400px">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100">
    <!-- begin="indefinite" allows us to start the animation from script -->
    <animate attributeName="x" begin="indefinite" dur="2s" from="10" to="300" fill="freeze" />
  </rect>
</svg>

<button onclick="go();">Go</button>
```

*(W3C 2018, "SVG Animations Level 2, Editor’s Draft", https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/), " Attributes to control the timing of the animation", "begin" attribute, "indefinite" value type, https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#TimingAttributes*