# Inline SVG doesn't scale

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to animate some vector graphics. Therefore I need to use svg inline or use something like https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody for external embedding in IE. So my HTML looks like this currently:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="chart" viewBox="0 0 1042 1024"><!-- SVG CODE --></symbol>
</svg>

<svg role="img" class="icon" width="200" height="200">
  <use xlink:href="#chart"></use>
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEWjvX

But as you might see the SVG is pretty small, although I used `width` both in the HTML and CSS (not sure if I need both?). It just doesn't scale. According to many articles I read about this problem (like this one http://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/ or http://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) it should work that way. What am I doing wrong?

*FYI: I used icomoon to create the SVG sprite and Illustrator to create the SVGs. To animate the SVG I gave most of the paths a class name, if that makes any difference.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand clearly what's the problem you're asking for help so I'll try to answer a maximum I saw in your snippet.

- If you can't see the `chart`, I think it's more because of the default `fill` color being black, than because of the size. If you add `fill: #FFF` into your `#wrapper`'s css or in an appropriate `svg{}` statement, you'll see it clearly.
- If your compass is so small, I think it's because your drawn pathes only are 50px large in a 1024x1024 document. (You're setting a `viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"` to your `<symbol>` element but setting it to something like `0 0 50 50` will help if you want to use transformations later, or even better, redraw it in a document where they fit right).
- You say that you want to animate those graphics. There are actually a lot of ways to do so. You can look to [**CSS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) animations (via a style sheet) or [**SMIL**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) (directly in the inline svg)  or via javascript (by modifying directly the [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) as noticed in [Nicholas Kyriakides](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1814486/nicholas-kyriakide's) answer). Look at the examples in the snippet below.

```js
var scale = 1;
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('p').addEventListener('click', function(){document.getElementById('linked').setAttribute('transform', 'scale('+(scale+=.1)+')');}, false);
document.getElementById('m').addEventListener('click', function(){document.getElementById('linked').setAttribute('transform', 'scale('+(scale-=.1)+')');}, false);
};
```

```css
.icon {
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 }
.wrapper {
 background: black;
 width: 80%;
 max-width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 color:#fff;
 fill: #fff;
 }
text {
 cursor: pointer;
 }
.icon:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 }
.icon:hover .chart{
 fill: #FAF;
 -webkit-animation: color 5s;
 animation: color 5s forwards alternate;
 }
@-webkit-keyframes color{ 
  0%{ fill : #FFF;}
  10%{ fill : #508694;}
  50%{fill: #FBB03B;}
  90%{ fill : #D19B6F;}
  100%{ fill : #FFF;}
  }
@keyframes color{ 
  0%{ fill : #FFF;}
  10%{ fill : #508694;}
  50%{fill: #FBB03B;}
  90%{ fill : #D19B6F;}
  100%{ fill : #FFF;}
  }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
 <symbol id="chart" viewBox="0 0 1042 1024">
  <path class="chart" d="M893.78 455.769h145.017v568.231h-145.017v-568.231z"  />
  <path class="chart" d="M671.815 0h145.017v1024h-145.017v-1024z"  />
  <path class="chart bar3" d="M446.89 624.462h145.017v396.578h-145.017v-396.578z"  />
  <path class="chart" d="M224.925 227.884h145.017v796.116h-145.017v-796.116z"  />
  <path class="chart" d="M0 71.029h145.017v952.971h-145.017v-952.971z"  />
 </symbol>
 <symbol id="compass" viewBox="0 0 46.6 46.6">
  <path class="compas__outer" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M22.7,0C10.2,0,0,10.2,0,22.7c0,12.5,10.2,22.7,22.7,22.7   c12.5,0,22.7-10.2,22.7-22.7C45.4,10.2,35.3,0,22.7,0L22.7,0z M22.7,42.9c-11.1,0-20.1-9-20.1-20.1c0-11.1,9-20.1,20.1-20.1   c11.1,0,20.1,9,20.1,20.1C42.9,33.8,33.8,42.9,22.7,42.9L22.7,42.9z M22.7,42.9"/>
  <path class="compass__needle" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M24.7,20.7C24,20,23,19.7,22,19.9l1.5-1.5l-12-6.9l6.9,12l1.5-1.5   c-0.2,0.9,0,2,0.8,2.7c0.7,0.7,1.8,1,2.7,0.8L21.9,27l12,6.9l-6.9-12l-1.5,1.5C25.7,22.5,25.5,21.4,24.7,20.7L24.7,20.7z    M21.8,23.6c-0.5-0.5-0.5-1.3,0-1.8c0.5-0.5,1.3-0.5,1.8,0c0.5,0.5,0.5,1.3,0,1.8C23.1,24.1,22.3,24.1,21.8,23.6L21.8,23.6z    M31.9,31.9l-8.7-5.1l3.7-3.7L31.9,31.9z M31.9,31.9">
   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="0s" dur="2s" type="rotate" from="0 22.7 22.7" to="360 22.7 22.7" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
 </symbol>
 <symbol id="linked-in" viewBox="0 0 1070 1024">
  <path d="M241.778 1024v-689.778h-227.556v689.778h227.556zM128 238.222c78.222 0 128-53.333 128-120.889s-46.222-117.333-128-117.333c-78.222 0-128 49.778-128 120.889 0 64 49.778 117.333 128 117.333v0 0zM369.778 1024c0 0 3.556-625.778 0-689.778h227.556v99.556c28.444-46.222 85.333-117.333 209.778-117.333 149.333 0 263.111 99.556 263.111 309.333v394.667h-227.556v-366.222c0-92.444-32-156.444-117.333-156.444-64 0-99.556 42.667-117.333 85.333-7.111 14.222-7.111 35.556-7.111 56.889v384h-231.111z" fill="#FFF"/>
 </symbol>
</svg>

<div class="wrapper">
 <h1>CSS @keyframe</h1>
 <svg role="img" class="icon" width="400" height="200">
 <!-- I had to get it out of the <use> because webkit browsers #@ø‡~! http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/lshrp-->
  <g id="chart">
   <path class="chart" d="M172.1,90.6H200V200h-27.9V90.6L172.1,90.6z"/>
   <path class="chart" d="M129.3,2.8h27.9V200h-27.9L129.3,2.8L129.3,2.8z"/>
   <path class="chart" d="M86,123.1H114v76.4H86V123.1L86,123.1z"/>
   <path class="chart" d="M43.3,46.7h27.9V200H43.3L43.3,46.7L43.3,46.7z"/>
   <path class="chart" d="M0,16.5h27.9V200H0C0,200,0,16.5,0,16.5z"/>
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#chart" id="charts" x="100"></use>
 </svg>
 <h1>SMIL animateTransfrom</h1>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 80%; height: 70px; overflow: visible">
  <use xlink:href="#compass"></use>
 </svg>
 <h1>Javascript</h1>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
  <use xlink:href="#linked-in" id="linked"></use>
  <text id="p" font-size="200" y="140" x="650">+</text>
  <text id="m" font-size="200" y="140" fill="" x="800">-</text>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think my main issue was the weird scaling of the SVG icons. But as you pointed out the viewport sizes are a little bit messed up. That's probably why... I will need to fix those to see if it works out. I have one question though: I don't need to animate svg on hover for this project, but on class changes of a parent element (e.g. click or scroll to a certain point). Do I have to use <g> instead of <symbol> too in that case for Webkit browsers? Or do I only have to use <g> if I want to animate on hover?

Comment: @demrks Well, it really depends on what you want to animate and how you will animate it. It's pretty easy to [combine javascript and SMIL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8458825/3702797). But yes, if you decide to use CSS (which I should confess isn't my favorite) you probably should reformat your document in order to avoid `<use>` elements. i.e check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5ckhyr9/1/) with a chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

Try this; change the viewBox of the symbol to be closer to size it was designed in.  I did a quick look for the outer dimensions of the paths, then assumed 100x100.

```
<symbol id="compass" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/rfornal-ssi/pen/GgWMvZ

I only adjusted one part, assuming that you can more forward with the rest of the code from this point.

**UPDATE**:
Based on testing by the OP, we learned that add viewBox to the `<svg>` tag itself **is not needed** since `<symbol>` tags are used.

Comment: Thanks, I think icomoon messed up the viewport sizes, I'll try it manually. I'm not sure about the viewBox on the <svg> though. According to this article (http://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/) you don't need that if u use <symbol>?

Comment: It may be that you don't need it ... I did set the SVG viewBox before I did the symbol in testing.  Post a comment here depending on which way works for you and I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: I just tested it. Seems to work without the viewBox on the <svg> element if you use <symbol>. I just had to fix the viewBox on the <symbol>. Thanks!