# Scroll along a path, curves & lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, path, scroll, jquery-animate

Does someone know about an simpler (less bloated) function/plugin to calculate custom scrollpath's like jquery.scrollpath from Joel Besada?

What i need is a way to let an DOM-Node move along a predefined path. I know about Math.cos & Math.sin (to move along curves) but I'm not really a math genius.

Comment: Seems like this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438830/move-a-div-in-a-curved-path-like-tweening-in-flash-old-days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it!

```
// Shamelessly stolen and ported from https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path
$.fn.arc = function (options) {
    options = $.extend({}, {
        center: [0, 0],
        radius: 0,
        start: 0,
        end: 0,
        dir: 1,
        rotate: true
    }, options);

    while (options.start > options.end && options.dir > 0) {
        options.start -= 360;
    }

    while (options.start < options.end && options.dir < 0) {
        options.start += 360;
    }

    var css = {};
    return this.each(function(){
        var self = $(this),
            win = $(window),
            doc = $(document);

        win.scroll(function(){
            var now = 1 - (1 * win.scrollTop() / (doc.height() - win.height())),
                a = (options.start * (now) + options.end * (1 - (now))) * Math.PI / 180;

            css.left = (Math.sin(a) * options.radius + options.center[0] + 0.5) | 0;
            css.top = (Math.cos(a) * options.radius + options.center[1] + 0.5) | 0;

            if(options.rotate){
                css.transform = "rotate(" + Math.atan2(options.center[1] - css.top, options.center[0] - css.left) + "rad)";
            }
            self.css(css);
        });
    });
};
```