# how to make my image curve the corners instead of stopping and moving

Tags: css, css-animations

I want my image to make smooth turns when it reaches a point. but I dont know how hope you can help? I am trying to code this in css only because I don't know javascript and ajax that well

```
//image     
div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        position: relative;

    //attrib
        -webkit-animation-name: Player1;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 5;
        -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
        -webkit-animation-play-state: running;

    }

    //path
    @-webkit-keyframes Player1 {
        0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
        25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
        50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
        75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}

    }
```

And if it was a image of a car how do I make it face in the direction of the path it is traveling?

Comment: I dont see any java nor Javascript in this question, that's why i removed the "java" tag. Java is not Javascript. Please explain what you mean with: "*and if it was a image of a car how do I make it face in the direction of the path it is traveling?*". How should the path or the image know, what is the front of the car?

Comment: So essentially you are asking how to make a CSS animation follow a curve or bezier?

Comment: @NicoO I have read that this can be done with Javascript(Mootools) or JQuery. and the image is now traveling in a clockwise direction and if the image was a car the car should rotate in order for the headlight to face in the direction it is going as it completes the laps

Comment: I'm not certain what you are trying to do, but perhaps it could be solved with CSS transformations and changing the transformation origin (http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/). That way, you can rotate the car around a fixed point.

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/

Comment: I am trying to recreate the NPC's of this game. I want the same effect of the spawend cars  https://marcqualie.com/2012/04/javascript-racing-game-prototype

Comment: You would need to use JavaScript to recreate an animation that complex. If it's as simple as moving a "car" in a predefined circle, that can be easily done using CSS transformations and animations. Your problem would appear to be better solved using HTML5 Canvas or SVG. Here's a great SO question that covers animations using Bezier curves: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438830/move-a-div-in-a-curved-path-like-tweening-in-flash-old-days